# File cannot be deleted .file is open in java tm SE library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Trying to upload a zipped multipart file. Writing in a particular location. But unable to delete the file. After unzipping.. Tried using `fileObj.delete` but no use !!

Just a sample code:

```
 DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);

        // Create a new file upload handler
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
        List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

        // Process the uploaded file items
        Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) 
        {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem) i.next();
            if (!fi.isFormField())
            {
                fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fi.getName());
                String contentType = fi.getContentType();
                long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
                logger.info("File name is::"+fileName);
                logger.info("content type is ::"+ contentType);
                logger.info("size is::"+sizeInBytes);

                // Write the file

                fileObj = new File(dirObj, clientFileName+".zip");
                fi.write(fileObj);
  return fileObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must close the file when done with it.  Windows does not allow the deletion of open files.